# Imagemagick API: MagickQuantizeImage vs. MagickTransformImageColorspace

Tags: imagemagick, magickwand

To convert an image to grayscale, I've tried:

`MagickQuantizeImage(wand, 256, GRAYColorspace, 0, MagickFalse, MagickFalse);`

and

`MagickTransformImageColorspace(wand, GRAYColorspace);`

in my program and both works as expected.

But what's the difference between them? Image quality? Side effects? Effiency?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess, and it is a guess, would be `flexibility`. The former allows more fine-grained control whereas the latter applies defaults that happen to be adequate for your purposes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's exactly the difference. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, and it is a guess, would be ***flexibility***. The former allows more fine-grained control whereas the latter applies defaults that happen to be adequate for your purposes.